# Is this the correct jQuery to change the class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little project I am working on and I am using jQuery. I tried using a little jQuery to change the class to change some css styles when clicked but it does not seem to work.

heres the important html:

```
<ul id="UInavList">
        <li class="selectedNav"><a href="javascript:;">My Activity</a></li>
        <li ><a href="javascript:;">My Tests</a></li>
        <li ><a href="javascript:;">Messaging</a></li>
        <li ><a href="javascript:;">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and heres the javascript:

```
$('#UInavList li').click( function() {
    $('#UInavList li').removeClass('selectedNav');
    $(this).addClass('selectedNav');
})
```

If you want to see all the code go here: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/XXXwL/

Comment: @chrome dude , your click is not working, let me debug.

Comment: @gov that was what I was figuring but I am new to jQuery and was not exactly sure, thanks

Comment: Please post code samples that don't require people to click external links to answer your question.

Comment: @jcm ok, thanks, I just updated that, sorry about that.

Comment: something wrong in this code.... $('#UInavList li').removeClass('selectedNav');
    $(this).addClass('selectedNav');

Comment: @chrome dude , the problem is with that ULNavList li inside code which is breaking, please change that to this and try the options as others suggested, I just wrote this to tell you the problem.

Comment: The "href" attributes on those anchor tags should just be "#".  Don't use the "javascript:" pseudo-protocol unless you really, really have to; in this case it's pointless.

Comment: Run your code in a `$(function() { ... })` initialization block also - the way it is now it won't work.

Comment: @Pointy, jQuery code does not need to be in that `$(function() { ... })` block.  That is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` which is an event binding for the ready-event which fires when the DOM has finished loading.  It performs no additional initialisation in and of itself.

Comment: @Orbling, maybe so but that is what fixed my problem. I am not exactly sure why but it did. I just tried removing that and it does not work without it.

Comment: @chromedude You may well need it in your code, it is usually essential to wait till the DOM is initialised before running code on it.  I was just pointing out that the ready() block is not always needed in order to make jQuery code work per se.

Comment: @Orbling it's not necessary unless it's necessary :-)  In this case, the `<script>` block containing the code came **before** the HTML markup that it intended to affect. The `<ul>` element targeted by the selector *did not exist* at the point the code was executed. By putting the code in a "ready" handler, @chromedude made it work because by that time, the `<ul>` **does** exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code already works in jsfiddle, you just hadn't set the framework to include jQuery on the right hand side - also with no class set to see the changes, it was hard to tell if it worked.

Look at this demo, it is identical to yours except it has a CSS entry to show up the change and I set the jQuery option on the side.

http://jsfiddle.net/XXXwL/8/

I would however target the anchor rather than the `li` itself and use `$(this).closest('li').addClass('selectedNav');` as the second line for preference, remembering to return false if you target an anchor with click() so that the href is not followed.

Comment: even after setting it as jquery , its not working for me , place a alert inside that code , it never fires

Comment: Well on my screen it works fine, which browser are you using? I'm in Chrome. Version with alert: http://jsfiddle.net/XXXwL/14/

Comment: This version targets the anchor as I mentioned in my answer, that might work better in the browsers that have trouble with the anchors being there: http://jsfiddle.net/XXXwL/15/

Answer (score 2):

One way to go:

```
$('#UInavList li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('selectedNav').siblings().removeClass('selectedNav');
});
```

In order to avoid redundancy-related errors (typos), you could define the class name only once:

```
$('#UInavList li').click( function() {
    var name = "selectedNav";
    $(this).addClass(name).siblings().removeClass(name);
});
```

In this simple case, it seems to not be needed, but if you use the name more than twice, or your handler is more complex, you should consider it.

Answer (score 0):

replace ULNavlist li with this,,it should work

```
$(this).removeClass('selectedNav');
        $(this).addClass('selectedNav');
        alert("hello");
```

Comment: I don't think this really makes much sense.  What's the point of removing the class and then immediately re-adding it to the same element?